# Using PURE.js to fed the HTML with JSON

Tags: html, json, pure-js

Can i use pure.js and jquery to display my HTML content via Json?

The reason is to check if anybody has used this method before and have been successful.

url for ref: http://beebole.com/pure/documentation/get-started/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you still are looking for an answer to this question but simply, **yes**, you can use *pure.js* with *jQuery* to display content from JSON objects. It is very well integrated with *jQuery* and it also works well with AJAX calls.

I've been using *pure.js* for several years and personally think it is one of best JavaScript template engines. But, it has some limitations so may not be good to solve all the problems.

I included some pure.js usage examples in some my answers e.g.

- [is it possible to insert new html with pure.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14399899/1916110)
- [jQuery iterate through JSON dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217347/1916110)

If you made any attempts to integrate *pure.js* with *jQuery* and ran into problem, please share your code and we should be able to help you more.

I hope that will help.